# Memory leak calling .Net dll from C++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I'm getting a memory leak when calling a .Net dll from C++ in the function below. I'm thinking it is with the SafeArray declaration but I don't know how else to release the memory besides SafeArrayDestroyDescriptor.  What else am I missing?

```
VARIANT_BOOL SendPack(IDotNetDll* wb, WW_POLL pl)
{
    HRESULT hr = 0;
    VARIANT_BOOL bretval;

    BYTE destination = pl.uDest;
    BYTE raw[2];
    raw[0] = pl.uAPI;
    raw[1] = pl.uOpcode;
    SAFEARRAY* bytes = NULL;
    hr = SafeArrayAllocDescriptor(1, &bytes);

    bytes->cbElements = sizeof(raw[0]);
    bytes->rgsabound[0].cElements = sizeof(raw);
    bytes->rgsabound[0].lLbound = 0;
    bytes->pvData = raw;
    bytes->fFeatures = FADF_AUTO | FADF_FIXEDSIZE;
    wb->SendMessage(destination,(BYTE)4, bytes, VARIANT_FALSE,
        200.0,&bretval);

    SafeArrayDestroyDescriptor(bytes);
    return bretval;
}
```

Edit:
I also tried this method using a variant

```
VARIANT_BOOL SendPacket(IDotNetDll* wb, WW_POLL pl)
{
    HRESULT hr = 0;
    VARIANT_BOOL bretval;
    _variant_t var;
    void * pArrayData = NULL;

    var.vt = VT_ARRAY | VT_UI1;
    SAFEARRAYBOUND rgsabound1[1];
    rgsabound1[0].cElements = 5;
    rgsabound1[0].lLbound = 0;

    var.parray = SafeArrayCreate(VT_UI1, 1, rgsabound1);

    BYTE destination = pl.uDest;
    SafeArrayAccessData(var.parray, &pArrayData);
    BYTE raw[5];
    raw[0] = pl.uAPI;
    raw[1] = pl.uOpcode;
    raw[2] = pl.uPayLoad[0];
    raw[3] = pl.uPayLoad[1];
    raw[4] = pl.uPayLoad[2];
    memcpy(pArrayData, raw, 5);
    SafeArrayUnaccessData(var.parray);

    //Send packet
    wb->SendMessage(destination,
        (BYTE)4, 
        var.parray,
        VARIANT_FALSE,
        200.0, &bretval);
    var.Clear();
    return bretval;
}
```

Here is the memory usage from VS 2015 profiler[image: profiler results]

Comment: From this link, it doesn't look like you are using the Alloc function correectly.  Perhaps there should be a call to SafeArrayAllocData?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221407(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I added the following code
`hr = SafeArrayAllocData(bytes);`
The problem still exists.  I'm calling this function several times a second. For subsequent calls, can I update the raw[1] value without having to call SafeArrayAllocDescriptor again?

Comment: Maybe SafeArrayDestroyData has to be called as well?  I haven't used these functions so I can only offer general guidance.   How about allocating the data once and holding it for the life of the program?  It looks like the amount of memory is inconsequential

Comment: I tried adding SafeArrayDestroyData and it didn't resolve the issue

Comment: Are you sure the leak is in SendPacket?  The profiler seems to indicate the memory growth is in the function that is calling SendPacket, if I am reading it correctly.

Comment: To me it looks like it is in External Code, which is the dll

Comment: Try changing SendPacket to be a stub that just returns success. If you can run your tight loop then the memory growth is in the External Code.  If you let the process run for hours the heap continues to grow?  Best to be sure it is a leak for certain before putting in too much effort.